# what's the difference between a generic type param of ? and Object

Tags: java, generics

For example, is there any difference between these two method signatures?

```java
Something<?> doIt(Collection<?> collection)
```

and

```java
Something<Object> doIt(Colllection<Object> collection)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. This works with `?` but not with `Object`:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<>()
doIt(fooList)
```

The reason is that a `List<Foo>` is *not* a `List<Object>` even if `Foo` is an `Object`. Why? Imagine we had a class `Bar` unrelated to `Foo` and we wrote `doIt` like this:

```
void doIt(Collection<Object> collection) {
    collection.add(new Bar())
}
```

Now if we were allowed to call `doIt(fooList)`, we'd end up with a `List<Foo>` that contains a `Bar`!